# What are the various desktop streaming software used by justin.tv and similar sites?

Tags: live, streaming

I want to create a channel to which various users could stream their desktop. I’m looking for the best solution for them.

So far I’ve found [Dyyno](http://www.dyyno.com/) (free but too simple), [WireCast](http://www.telestream.net/) (expensive and too complex), and [Flash Media Live Encoder](https://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html) (free).

I need one that is free, simple to use, yet powerful enough (notably, it must be able to stream a specific area of the screen, and to include audio from the software or from the microphone or both, and to run on both Windows and Mac OS X).

Do you have any suggestions?

P.S. [LiveStream](http://livestream.com/) and [Ustream](http://www.ustream.tv/) have proprietary solutions (incompatible with others).

Comment: It's not clear if this is really on topic here, since the question is really more about using justin.tv in a particular way. It's not really video production. Meta discussion [here](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/204/are-non-production-video-and-audio-questions-on-topic-here)

Comment: @Warrior Bob I see it as production because when you're streaming your desktop you're producing video with several audio and video sources, you're mixing them, you're adding titles and special effects. The question has in fact little to do with justin.tv, as you can guess WireCast and Flash Media Live Encoder were not made specifically for justin.tv yet they work with it and that's what I'm looking for. I'm stating the obvious here, but maybe nobody on this site does streaming.

Comment: In your comment, you describe what sounds pretty clearly like video production - editing, mixing, effects, that sort of thing. But the question itself doesn't appear have any of this. Right now it reads like "how can I get video of my desktop onto some streaming site?" which is more like [a question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/10678) [I'd expect](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18254) [on webapps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18638). If the question is really more deeply about video than that, then an edit for clarification might be all that's necessary.

Comment: Also, please join the meta discussion if you think the site is being too restrictive! It's up to the community to define the scope of the site.

Comment: ispyconnect.com might be an inexpensive option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stream with Justin.TV, you can download FFSplit !

http://www.ffsplit.com/

It is still in a BETA State, but it does run quite well !

Don't forget to follow every instruction that is put on the site.

Good luck !